# Set action for submenu in AppIndicator

Tags: application-development, indicator, c

I am trying to build a simple indicator in C. This is my code:

```
void make_indicator(){
    //Making the indicator
    appindicator = app_indicator_new("My Indicator", "/home/alex/Qt/normal_tray_icon/a.png", APP_INDICATOR_CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS);

    //the construction of the main menu
    GtkWidget* indicatormenu = gtk_menu_new();
    //adding a submenu
    GtkWidget* submenu1 = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("SubMenu1");
    gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(submenu1), indicatormenu);

    /* HERE */
    //here comes the error! Adding an option to the submenu    
    GtkWidget* submenu1_option;
    submenu1_option = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Submenu option!");
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(submenu1), submenu1_option);

    //adding an option to the main menu and connecting it to a slot
    GtkWidget* showapp_option;

    showapp_option = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Show App!");
    g_signal_connect(showapp_option, "activate", G_CALLBACK(show_app), this);
    gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(indicatormenu), showapp_option);

    //showing the indicator
    gtk_widget_show_all(indicatormenu);
    app_indicator_set_status(appindicator, APP_INDICATOR_STATUS_ACTIVE);
    app_indicator_set_attention_icon(appindicator, "dialog-warning");

    app_indicator_set_menu(appindicator, GTK_MENU (indicatormenu));
}
```

I fail to add an action to a submenu. I add the submenu as a simple menu item, thus I cannot append to it actions, or can I?

I don't get error messages on compilation, but on run time I get:

```
(normal_tray_icon:9203): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from `GtkMenuItem' to `GtkMenuShell'

(normal_tray_icon:9203): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_menu_shell_insert: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL (menu_shell)' failed
```

which I can understand but I don't know how to solve.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created only item for submenu, not submenu.
This can be done in this way:

```
//adding a submenu:
//creating submenu
GtkWidget *submenu1 = gtk_menu_new();
GtkWidget *submenu1_item = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("SubMenu1");
gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(submenu1_item), submenu1);

//adding submenu to main menu
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(indicatormenu), submenu1_item);

//adding an option to the submenu    
GtkWidget* submenu1_option;
submenu1_option = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Submenu option!");
gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(submenu1), submenu1_option);
```